# How to remove multiple pipes in data frame?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, stringr, tidyverse

Here is simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

    > dataf <- data_frame(text = c('this is a pip||e |' ,
+                              'this is |||'))
> dataf
# A tibble: 2 x 1
                text
               <chr>
1 this is a pip||e |
2        this is |||
```

I want to replace all the pipes in the data with an empty string. Basically I want them to disappear. However, I am only able to get rid of one of them at a time:

```
     > dataf %>% mutate(text = str_replace(text, '\\|+', ""))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
              text
             <chr>
1 this is a pipe |
2         this is
```

What is wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: in base R, `gsub("\\|", "", 'this is |||')` works as does `sub("\\|+", "", 'this is |||')`.

Comment: thanks but with the new `stringr` is there a way as well?

Comment: Just confirmed that `str_replace(text, '\\|+', "")` will work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: a ha! the gsub solution does not work with the updated example.

Comment: `gsub` will work. maybe you meant the `sub` solution. That regex is designed to remove the first (set of) adjacent pipes. `gsub`, on the other hand will remove them all. You could even use `gsub("|", "", 'this is a pip||e |', fixed=TRUE)` to make it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_replace_all` from `stringr` to remove all the matched patterns:

```
dataf %>% mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, '\\|', ""))

# A tibble: 2 × 1
#            text
#           <chr>
#1 this is a pipe
#2       this is
```

Comment: I prefer Imo's answer. Let's embrace regex.

Comment: its nice to have multiple solution to simple problems

Comment: @Masoud Just like to point out there is a difference between `str_replace_all(, "\\|",..)` and `str_replace(,"\\+",..)`; Their difference is the same as the difference between `gsub` and `sub`; You can test this string with the two options "ab||cd|".

Comment: @Psidom I agree. That was a personal preference for this specific problem.